# variable data not available when called in other method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In my component, there are 3-4 methods along with `constructor(){...}` and `ngOnInit(){...}`. In class, I've declared one variable `values:any=[]` which is initialized with some json data in one method named as `getData()` in the same class.

```
getData(){
  this.service.getData().subscribe(res=>{
    this.values = res.json();
  })
}
```

now I called this method in `ngOnInit(){...}`. From this I can say that `values` is initialized with some data but if I call `values` in other method for the purpose of displaying data. It says empty array.

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  values:any=[];

  constructor(private service: AccountService) {
  }

  getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.values = res.json();
    })
  }

  callData(){
       console.log(this.values)  
   } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    this.callData();
  }
```

In the `callData()` , I have `console.log()` but this says that `values` is empty. Why???

Comment: have you got my point ?, is that worked for you ?

Comment: Yes @PranayRana I'm getting after using async/await but I have many lines of code. Basically I'm using angular-highcharts where I have to call the two charts. As I was facing the issue mentioned above, I have to call the http get method two times. Now maybe I will get the little optimized code.

Comment: gr8 ... i hope you got the point ..understanding concept is more important

Comment: @PranayRana but dude, I am facing problem while applying foreach in res.json()

Comment: You dont need to convert to json if your service method return you proper type , in your service.ts it should be like `getData() : Observable<retuntype>`..that should work

Comment: It worked, thanks dude. I'm new in Angular 5 because of this I'm getting many doubts and errors in real-time project.  :)

Comment: welcome..it happens when you start working on new thing ..you cannot become expert in onday ...:) \

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167078/discussion-between-yash-jain-and-pranay-rana).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you cannot get data there as you call to service i.e. http call to get data is not completed yet.

if you want to get data in callData method then make use of `async/await` like this

```
 async getData(){
     const res =  await this.service.getData().toPromise();
      this.values = res.json();
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getData();
    this.callData();
  }

  callData(){
       console.log(this.values)  
   }
```

Basically you have to wait for serverside call to finish, right now you are not waiting for serverside call to finish and thats the reason why you are not getting data in your `this.calllData()` method.

**or**

if you don't want to go for async/await then you can do this

```
getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.values = res.json();
      this.callData();
    })
  }

  callData(){
       console.log(this.values)  
   } 

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more solution which I used to handle similar case:-  using 'setTimeout' function.

```
  getData(){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.values = res.json();
    })
  }

  callData(){
       console.log(this.values)  
   } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.callData();
    }, 10);
  }
```

This way you can add a minimal wait time to code block which depends on values returned in response. I used it with value 1 millisecond and it had never failed for me.

Also on json traversal point, you could return the json directly from the service method. In order to traverse that object, instead of using 'foreach' you could try below code:

```
for(let key in json){
    let value = json[key];
    //rest of the code
}
```

Hope it helps!